# Minted & Fonts Types/Families

Tags: fonts, minted

I am typesetting some code in my document. In my preamble I include some packages to make the font a Times style font.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[varvw]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[
    linenos,
    breaklines,
    style = autumn,
    frame = single,
    fontsize = \footnotesize,
]{cpp}
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
double MyNum(5.32);
cout << "My number is " << MyNum << endl;
}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

I noticed that my code looks different then what is shown in the examples in the Minted package. I removed the `newtxtext` packages and it *does* look like the package. But beyond that, I can use a `fontfamily` key in the minted options which seems to change it differently depending on if the font of the document is computer modern or Times.

What am I observing when, for example, `fontfamily = courier` produces different looking output depending on if `\usepackage{newtxtext}` is or is not included?